Vamos oferecer recompensas
O meu objetivo com esta pergunta/inicitiva é reconhecer conteudo que tenha qualidade no site.
Todo e qualquer conteudo que considerem que seja vantajoso, educativo, bem explicado, pertinente ou que tenha quaisquer outras carecteristicas que considerem positivas.
Incluindo perguntas, respostas e perguntas sem resposta.
A titulo de exemplo eu dei recentemente uma recompensa para obter respostas a esta pergunta Qual método HTTP utilizar para pesquisar dados usando o request body?
Aproveitamos para incentivar responder algumas perguntas que não tenham resposta. Provavelmente não vai alterar significativamente o número de perguntas sem resposta, mas nem é esse o objetivo.
O objetivo é mostrar à comunidade que há bastante conteudo positivo e aumentar o engajamento.
E em vez de estarmos focados só no conteudo mau, temos exemplos atualizados de conteudos bons.

O problema não é a falta de bom conteúdo, mas a crescente quantidade de perguntas ruins (pra dizer o mínimo). Não sou contra a ideia, talvez até ajude, mas não acho que será uma medida efetiva, esse seu exemplo, não parece que causou muito engajamento, poucos comentários e votos. Ao que parece, a SE não tem interesse, pelo menos não o suficiente, em melhorar as coisas, sem o apoio deles, as medidas que podemos tomar são limitadas. Provavelmente, a melhor delas, é simplesmente não fazer nada e abandonar o site, assim como eles

@Costamilam Isso é o que já tenho feito também. Tive afastado de interagir com o site durante vários meses/anos. Mas vai na volta chego aqui e dou uma olhada para ver como as coisas estão. Talvez seja melhor não fazer nada.

Já foi tentado antes e na época até teve um certo efeito, porém limitado. Acho louvável qualquer tentativa de melhorar o site, mas como já dito acima, chegou num ponto que não depende apenas de nós meros usuários. A SE precisaria agir, mas eles estão em uma direção oposta à nossa. Enquanto queremos qualidade, eles buscam mais e mais quantidade (mesmo que não seja o discurso oficial, todas as ações apontam para isso). Como eu já disse antes, acho que o site já deu o que tinha que dar. Ainda vale pelo conteúdo antigo, mas o novo não se salva quase mais nada

Lá por 2018 até o começo de 2019, eu entrava no site todos os dias de forma fanática. Hoje, raramente entro no site. E quando entro, muito dificilmente acho alguma pergunta que valha a pena ser respondida, pois o site se tornou uma cidade fantasma. Infelizmente o SOpt já era.

Ando bem afastado do site, mas ofereci uma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/546971/existe-alguma-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-os-termos-rotina-e-sub-rotina
